# Wait script end before parsing HTML

Tags: javascript, html

My webpage is handling a user login in JavaScript. After the user login completed I have access to all user information.

I'm using Firebase Auth to log the user. I have a login page which works. In my main page, I have a script that check if the user is logged or not:

```
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
            if (user) {
                // User is signed in.
                currentUser = user;

                if (user != null) {
                    user.providerData.forEach(function (profile) {
                        console.log("Sign-in provider: " + profile.providerId);
                        console.log("--Provider-specific UID: " + profile.uid);
                        console.log("--Name: " + profile.displayName);
                        console.log("--Email: " + profile.email);
                        console.log("--Photo URL: " + profile.photoURL);
                    });
                }
            } else {
                // No user is signed in.
                console.log("No user is signed in.");
            }
})
```

I want to display user's information on the page with html code. That means display his name, profile picture and other stuff like that.

The problem is that the html code is parsed before the data is fetched. So it displays nothing.

I don't know if it's the good way to this but I would like to know how to make the parsing of the html page wait for login completion.

Like I said I'm a beginner so I don't have enough knowledge to take the good decisions and find the best ways to do something. I'm sure there is another solution I don't know to bypass this situation.

Comment: Unfortunately, it's not really clear what you are trying to ask here.

Comment: Ok sorry trying to correct that.

Comment: Hope it's better now.

Comment: Hey Paul! From what I can see, are you using Ajax or a simple POST form with html? Also are you setting $_SESSION in php to track the logged in user?

Comment: Actually PHP  will not render HTML before the script end. Are you using AJAX?

Comment: I'm using Firebase Auth so it's just a simple script. I edit my question.

Comment: ok here is it guys